# Rstudio, ¿seleccionar todas las lineas de código mediante un comando?

Tags: r, rstudio

Acabo de empezar con el lenguaje de programación de R . He visto que a diferencia de la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación solo ejecuta las líneas seleccionadas, no todo el código. ¿Hay alguna forma de seleccionar todas las líneas de código sin tener que pasar todo el ratón por todo el editor de Rstudio?

Comment: `ctrl-a` +  `ctrl-enter`

Answer (score 0):

Con CTRL A seleccionas todo el código como explican mas arriba y luego lo ejecutas.

Otra forma que uso bastante es dirigiendo al final del código a compilar y luego usar el atajo ALT CTRL B

Otra opción que te sugiero investigar cuando se vuelve recurrente ejecutar siempre el mismo código, es tirarlo mediante un batch, lo cual básicamente es ejecutar un código mediante la consola de windows u otro terminal